# Can a dask.distributed cluster autoscale different workers independently?

Tags: kubernetes, dask, distributed

I'd like to set up a dask cluster with a number of different types of workers e.g. normal workers, high-memory workers, GPU workers, ...

As I understand it I can manually create the workers and tag them with [`resources`](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/resources.html#worker-resources). What I'd like to do is create a cluster, specifying the min/max number of each type of worker and have it autoscale the exact number of each type of worker based on the number of tasks requesting each type of worker/resource.

Is this possible now or is this something which is on the roadmap (issue I can subscribe to)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible now

As of 2020-02-15 this is not a supported behavior

> or is this something which is on the roadmap (issue I can subscribe to)?

Dask isn't centrally managed, and so doesn't have a roadmap.  I don't know of any issue about this today, but I wouldn't be surprised if one already existed.

Comment: From [gitter](https://gitter.im/dask/dask?at=5e46994a292ff243d3c8ec74) it seems https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/2208 is still the latest state for this feature